# KIBANA 4 process gets stopped on closing the putty window

Tags: kibana

I am using kibana-4.0.0-beta3 version on linux machine. The process gets stopped automatically on closing the putty window. Is there  any way to run the process in back-end?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As with any unix process, the basics would be to use 'nohup' and put the process in the background.  You should write a startup script (e.g. /etc/init.d/kibana4) that is similar in form to other startup scripts on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a kibana4 startup script for debian, simply place it in /etc/init.d/kibana , then run:
/etc/init.d/kibana start

set it to start on boot:

update-rc.d kibana defaults

https://github.com/akabdog/scripts/blob/master/kibana4_init

Answer (score 0):

Use a program called `screen` to run anything in a shell. Then detach from the terminal session but keep the processes running. When you reconnect you can reconnect to the session and interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

Run with `nohup`

```
nohub  ./bin/kibana
```

Answer (score 0):

bin/kibana > abc.txt &

This will run kibana in backend and redirect its logs to abc.txt. works like a charm for me :-)